# Using Nginx nodejs apps need to run with test1domain.com/directory

Tags: web-server, ubuntu-12.04, node.js

I have to run nodejs app with the url like http://test1domain.com/directory:

https://test1domain.com   == live website

https://test1domain.com/api1 == nodejs api

https://test1domain.com/api2 == nodejs api

*Current site and apps are running like:*

https://test1domain.com == Live Website

https://test1domain.com:8443 api1 == nodejs api

https://test1domain.com:3000 api2 == nodejs api

Please advise, is it possible?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by editing *vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default*

```
 location /api2/ {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    rewrite ^/api2/(.*) /$1 break;

 }

 location /api1/ {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8443;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    rewrite ^/api1/(.*) /$1 break;

 }
```

Its worked !